# Occasional high latency in qpid application

Tags: c++, linux, qpid

I'm hoping someone can help me with an issue I'm seeing with a Qpid C++ application I'm using. Essentially, we have one application publishing a status to a last_value_queue at about a 10Hz rate and a couple other applications continuously processing this status. The receivers also use the status as a kind of heartbeat and will complain if the status message isn't updated for a certain amount of time (500ms, to be exact.)

This works fine for about a day, after which we start seeing issues. Every couple hours, a single fetch call by a receiver will block for over 500ms (sometimes for up to 900ms.) This behavior will continue until we restart the broker.

I'm no expert, but I don't think I'm doing anything particularly dumb. I've been able to repeat this behavior with a pair of small applications that connect to the broker. Every 100ms the sender sends a std::chrono::time_point object set to the current time. The receiver fetches the message and calculates the delay to the millisecond. The delay is always 0ms or 1ms, except for the single spikes every hour or so after the initial day of everything being happy. The connection is created like so:

```
qpid::messaging::Connection c("host1:5672","{ reconnect: true}");
```

and the sender and receiver are both created with the string

```
"testQueue; { mode: browse, create: always, node: { type: queue, x-declare:{ arguments:{'qpid.last_value_queue_key':'key','qpid.replicate':'none'}}}}"
```

High availability replication is enabled on the broker, but I have it explicitly disabled for everything for the purpose of my testing. I see no difference in behavior when the broker and apps are running on the same host or different hosts on the LAN. Using qpid-stat, I can see that the broker replication queue is still transmitting quite a bit of data, but its message count is always at 0 so I don't think it's sending more than it can handle. Can anyone think of anything I might be missing that could cause this behavior? We're using the Qpid 0.26 and the C++ broker.